# Blueprints and the User model

Tags: database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I recently started playing with flask and to do so I have been developing a little sandbox web app that will serve as a container for other projects I have in mind. So far I focused on implementing a user system and I everything seems to be working. I also implemented my version of user roles control.

Now I want to start to develop the other aspects of the web app. Let's say, for example, I want to develop a blog, my own image storage, an achievement system for a group of my friends, etc. My intention is to use the same User model for all of the sub applications and I've been trying to draw how such relationship would look like, but I haven't thought of anything different then adding all of them into my main User class. My concern is that by doing so the User class will end up being too big, with many relationships attached; besides, not every user will have access/need for each of the sub applications.

Is there a better way to 'link' my user with other sub applications?

### File structure

```
-- MyApp
   -- auth_blueprint
      -- forms.py
      -- routes.py
      -- models.py
      -- utils.py
   -- achievements_blueprint
      -- forms.py
      -- routes.py
      -- models.py
   [static, templates, etc]
```

### User Class

```
from myapp import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin
from flask import url_for

from random import randint
from os import listdir

__PROFILE_PICS_PATH = 'myapp/static/media/img/profile_pics/'

def new_profile_pic():
    pics = listdir(__PROFILE_PICS_PATH)
    if '.DS_Store' in pics:
        pics.remove('.DS_Store')
    n_pics = len(pics)
    return '/static/media/img/profile_pics/'+ str(randint(1, n_pics)) +'.png'

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

# Define a base model for other database tables to inherit
class Base(db.Model, UserMixin):

    __abstract__  = True

    id            = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_created  = db.Column(db.DateTime,  default=db.func.current_timestamp())
    date_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime,  default=db.func.current_timestamp(),
                                        onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp())

# Define a User model
class User(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    first_name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='First Name')
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, default='Last Name')
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False) 
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default=new_profile_pic())

    # Define the relationship to Role via UserRoles
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='user_roles')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}','{self.email}','{self.image_file}')"

    def has_roles(self, role_names):
        return len([role for role in self.roles if role.name in role_names])


# Define the Role data-model
class Role(Base, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'

    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)

# Define the UserRoles association table
class UserRoles(Base, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_roles'

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('roles.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

### If I were to add, for instance, a mini blog This is what I would do:

```
-- MyApp
   -- blog_blueprint
      -- forms.py
      -- routes.py
      -- models.py
[etc]
```

### 1. Create the necessary models at blog_bluprint/models.py

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

### 2. And then add the relationship to the User model

```
posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
```

### Thanks for any help!

Comment: Will all users have access to all sub-applications?

Comment: Hi there @SuperShoot, thanks for the interest and for your time! No, they won't. My idea is that a user will have only have access to the sub applications that are useful to him.